# how to dock three panels on same winform in VS2010

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

My goal is to have three panels on one winform and each of them has one listview which docked onto it so that when maximize window, all listview componenets gets automatically resized properly.

As I understand, docking is the the way to go, but it seems I can only dock one listview per panel and one penal per winform, does anyone know a better soluton? 
this is in VS2010 c# I am using .net3.5 but Im not limited to any specific versions, but prefer using older version for comaptibility

Comment: Which version of .NET are you using? VS2010 can target several different versions. Which one are you using?

Comment: .net 3.5 but I can go with any version of .net if necessary

Comment: @ikel `but it seems I can only dock one listview per panel and one penal per winform,` You can doc multiple panels on single Form and multiple listview in a single panel. is that you are trying to figure out?

Comment: You can dock any number of panels on the form.  Pretty unlikely that you actually want that, surely you are looking for a TableLayoutPanel instead.

Comment: @HansPassant, thank you my friend, that's excatly what i need for now. can you answer my question please so that i can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted, you can dock more than one panel in a form.  But only one of them can be Dock = Fill, the others won't resize automatically.  Unless you add the code to do so in the OnResize override.

A TableLayoutPanel can resize all panels automatically.